# Scroll without calling scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This web has this layout:

```
section1

section2

section3

section4

section5
```

Each section covers the entire screen height. I need the web to scroll to the middle (section3) while I'm preloading images, for that, I use:

```
var targetOffset = $('#home-nav-bar').offset().top - 183;
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset }, 100);
```

This effect is not visible to the user, because I trigger it while the preloader loads the images.

But this web also uses the parallax effect, which I'm achieving with `stellar.js`. The problem I have is that the `.animate` fires the scroll event on the page, and triggers the stellar code, which moves my elements away from where they should be after the preloading finishes. Is there any way that I can "scroll" to section3 without using .animate which triggers `stellar.js`?

Comment: Perhaps write the parallaxing yourself and don't use stellar. Or rearrange your markup so the preloader doesn't have to scroll while loading.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved it using the offset settings provided by the plugin, putting data-stellar-vertical-offset="offsetNumber" in each section.